# How do I install a Bootstrap theme generator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how to recreate Bootstrap's generator. To provide some background information, Twitter Bootstrap features a way to customize your build through a nicely designed customize page here:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

I downloaded and installed the docs, https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/docs, from the Bootstrap GitHub project with the intention of recreating and tweaking the the customize page on my own server.

However, in order it to work, I need some kind of backend generator that populates the variables from the customize page into the appropriate LESS files, etc. I believe the public Bootstrap generator runs at http://bootstrap.herokuapp.com/ (from looking at the JS ajax call).

How do I recreate it? Are there any public options out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creators of Bootstrap have the project in their Github accounts. It is built with node and you can download the full source code in the repository [twitter/bootstrap-server](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap-server).

Answer (score 1):

as we know , bootstrap in an open source project . get it from here : [bootstrap server](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap-server)